# Broken anchors in Docusaurus that appear to be correct

Tags: docusaurus

I'm trying to upgrade a project to Docusaurus v3, and I'm getting an error saying I have broken anchors. But I can’t find anything online that shows me how what in the file is incorrect in any way. The error is pointing me to links to a page called Carbon Budget in the Glossary, which is a link that exists on a number of pages. Here's the code of one of those anchors, as well as a screenshot of where it directs to in the glossary. It seems to be correct, so I'm not sure how I can get the error to resolve.

```
:::tip 72-144.3 Gigatons will be saved from our [carbon budget](../glossary/#carbon-budget)
```

:::

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reformatting the link to `[carbon budget](../glossary.md#carbon-budget)` or `[carbon budget](../glossary#carbon-budget)`

Both should work but think the / may be the issue